# How does QGIS know there is a plugin update?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I've created a plugin and hosting the installation zip and xml file on a local network repository (for company use). Everything works fine but every time a user opens QGIS, it shows that the plugin has an update when nothing has been updated. The issue looks like this:

[image: There is a new version available]

Is there something in the repository xml file that flags QGIS that the plugin has an update available? How can I control this so it only flags when there is actually an update?

Answer (score 5):

The `QGIS-plugin` manager matches the version number of any locally installed QGIS plugin (this includes your development version) with the version number hosted on the QGIS plugin repo.

As you can see in your screenshot your locally installed version has the version number **0.1**, while the one on the repo has **1.1**.
Thus it correctly assumes that the one on the server is a new version of the plugin. Just set the version number accordingly in your metadata file.

Comment: I guess the metadata.txt of the plugin has another version number stored than the repository xml file.

Comment: Thanks Curlew. That worked perfectly. I had forgotten about the metadata file.